# How to use another function to break out of a while loop under certain conditions?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use another function running in my while loop to break out of it under certain conditions. I have been writing practice code to try attempt it but it doesn't seem to break... it just keeps running infinitely

```
global test

def is_True():
    test = True

for i in range(5):
    test = False
    print("Run number:",i)

    while(test==False):
        print("the is_True method hasn't been called yet")
        is_True()
        print("The is__True method was called")
```

Comment: return the result from is_True

Comment: Return the result in `is_True`, and put `if not is_True(): break` in the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put the `global` statement in the wrong place. It goes *in* the function to indicate that `test` is not a local variable. A `global` statement at the global scope is basically a no-op.

```
def is_True():
    global test
    test = True
```

That said, try to avoid global variables when possible. Have `is_True` return `True` instead and assign the return value to `test` in the calling scope.

```
def is_True():
    return True

while not test:
    print("...")
    test = is_True()
    print("...")
```

Answer (score 3):

Modify the is_True() function:

```
def is_True():
    return True
```

and, inside the loop, assign it to test:

```
test = is_True()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the `test` variable is being defined as a local variable in the function is_true() and is not using the global variable `test`. The simplest way to solve this would be to tell python to use the *global* variable test. You do that by changing:

```
test = True
```

to

```
global test 
test = True
```

That is not, however, the best way to go about this. The best way to go about this would be to do what @Vasilis D or @Colin suggest, which would be to return a value from the is_True() function and use that instead:

```
def is_True():
    return True

for i in range(5):
    test = False
    print("Run number:",i)

    while(test==False):
        print("the is_True method hasn't been called yet")
        test = is_True()
        print("The is__True method was called")
```

Using global variables is, in general, frowned upon because it can create confusing situations where you define two different variables with the same name and are unsure of which one you're modifying.

Comment: Woops, fixed  @chepner

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the other answers mention how to fix this, but I figured it would also be helpful to explain why this isn't working, to help in the future.

In `is_True`, when you assign to test, you're making a new local variable, instead of refering to the global variable named `test`. If you want to refer to the global, add `global test` to the start of `is_True`. This will tell python that you want to refer to the global variable, not make a new local.

Of course, you probably shouldn't be using global variables for this, so a better solution is to return `True` from `is_True()` and do `test = is_True()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around I've seen :

First, allow the method `is_True` to have a return type, a boolean, True/False, i.e:

```
def is_True():
    test = True
    return test
```

Then, allow the while loop to reinitialize the variable test to the return type of `is_True` i.e :

```
        print("The is_True method hasn't been called yet")
        test = is_True()
```

This is because, I suspect, the variable in the method `is_True` is private and only available within that method. Thus it doesn't affect the state of your global variable : `test` . 
Overall, the program should resemble this:

```
global test

def is_True():
    test = True
    return test

for i in range(5):
    print("Run number:",i)
    test = False
    while(test==False):
        print("The is_True method hasn't been called yet")
        test = is_True()
        print("The is_True method was called")
```

I hope this answers your question, and happy coding!